# Angular unit test failing even when configuring correctly spies

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My component looks like this:

```
  constructor(
    private readonly dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ChangeRolesDialogComponent>,
    private readonly rolesService: RolesService,
    private readonly usersService: UsersService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rolesService.getAllRoles().subscribe((roles: Role[]) => {
      this.roles = roles;
    });
 
  }
```

In the configuration of the .spec file, I did this:

```
fdescribe('ChangeRolesDialogComponent', () => {
  let component: ChangeRolesDialogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChangeRolesDialogComponent>;

  let rolesServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<RolesService>;
  let usersServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<UsersService>;
  let matDialogRefSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MatDialogRef<ChangeRolesDialogComponent>>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    rolesServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('RolesService', ['getAllRoles']);
    usersServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UsersService', [
      'getCurrentUserAuthentication',
    ]);

    matDialogRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialogRef', ['close']);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ChangeRolesDialogComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: RolesService, useValue: rolesServiceSpy },
        { provide: UsersService, useValue: usersServiceSpy },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: matDialogRefSpy },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
      ],
```

And this is the unit test:

```
 it('should get all roles on init', () => {
    const roles: Role[] = [Role.ADMINISTRATORS, Role.PRICING_ADMIN];
    rolesServiceSpy.getAllRoles.and.returnValue(of(roles));

    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(component.roles).toEqual(roles);
  });
```

but it's failing with error:

"should get all roles on init FAILED
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')"

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The method `getAllRoles` must return an observable that can be subscribed.

```
rolesServiceSpy.getAllRoles.and.returnValue(of({}));
```

You can change the `of({})` to a real value of a `Role` object that you've defined